# tablesorter grabbing original data after my dropdown filter

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablesorter

I have a table with a few rows in it that is sortable using tablesorter.

```
<tbody id='filterTicket_body'>
 <tr><td>Field 1 Row 1</td><td>Field 2 Row 1</td><td>Field 3 Row 1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Field 1 Row 2</td><td>Field 2 Row 2</td><td>Field 3 Row 2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Field 1 Row 3</td><td>Field 2 Row 3</td><td>Field 3 Row 3</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

On the same page i have a dropdown that user can filter rows. that drop down fires an ajax call to db to get only results based on filter. I clear the #filterTicket_body and then replace it with results.

```
        $('body').on('change','#ticketFilter',function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
            $('#filterTicket_body').html('');
            $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"support/ticketFilter.php",
                    data:"filter="+val,
                    success:function(result){
                            $('#filterTicket_body').html(result);
                    }
            });

    });
```

An example of result would just be a table row.

```
 <tr><td>Field 1 Row 2</td><td>Field 2 Row 2</td><td>Field 3 Row 3</td></tR>
```

Lets assume the user selected "Row 2".  This filter would replace #filterTicket_body with 1 row of data. So far so good.

Now, when a user clicks on table header to sort, using default tablesorter,  the original 3 rows of data are prepended to the results. so I end up with

```
Row 2
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to destroy the tablesorter event and recreate it after successful ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to update tablesorter's internal cache by triggering an update event:

```
success:function(result){
    $('#filterTicket_body')
         .html(result)
         .trigger('update');
}
```